# Adding a timeout to discord bot with threading library python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, python-multithreading

I have been working on a bot that accepts votes to kick a user then re-invites them and gives them their roles back. I made it go 24/7 and realized I need a timeout so that if the vote doesn't complete after a few minutes, the voting will be reset and a new vote can be called. I tried using the Threading library but I cant get it to work properly.

```
import threading
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


def reset():
    global vote_started
    global users_voted
    vote_started = False
    users_voted.clear()
    print('[+] Timeout Finished')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def votekick(ctx, *, member: discord.Member, Reason=None):
    global vote_started
    global users_needed
    global kicked_user
    global member_to_be_kicked
    global channel
    global role
    t = threading.Timer(120.0, reset) <===== This should call reset function after 120 seconds
    if member == client.user:
        await ctx.send('[-] ok retard')
        return
    else:
        if not vote_started:
            kicked_user = member
            member_to_be_kicked = member
            vote_started = True
            users_voted.append(ctx.author.id)
            await ctx.channel.send(
                f'[+] A votekick has started to kick {member.display_name}. [{len(users_voted)}/{users_needed}]')
            t.start    <======== This should start the reset function if this is the first vote counted
            print('[+] Timeout Started')
        else:
            if ctx.author.id in users_voted:
                await ctx.send('[-] Error: You have already voted.')
            else:
                if member != member_to_be_kicked:
                    await ctx.send(f'[-] A vote to kick {member_to_be_kicked.display_name} has already started. nice '
                                   f'try retard.')
                    return
                users_voted.append(ctx.author.id)
                if len(users_voted) < users_needed:
                    await ctx.channel.send(f'[+] Users voted: [{len(users_voted)}/{users_needed}]')
                else:
                    pass
        if len(users_voted) >= users_needed:
            invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(reason=None, max_uses=1)
            try:
                dm_channel = await member.create_dm()
                await dm_channel.send(invite)
            except:
                pass
            await ctx.channel.send(
                f"[+] [{len(users_voted)}/{users_needed}] users have voted to kick {member.display_name}.")
            await member.kick(reason=Reason)
            vote_started = False
            users_voted.clear()
            role = member.roles
            channel = ctx.channel
```

When I run this, I thought the reset function should have been called, but in the logs, I see `[+] Timeout Started` but not `[+] Timeout Finished` like I expected. This means the reset function is never called. What do I need to do to fix this. I am using python 3.9.4 with the discord rewrite.

Comment: Maybe try using a [task](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) as your reset command and then after some time stop it within itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer will never start, because you haven't initialized the `t.start()` function

Just add parentheses to `t.start` and timer will start, when you'll try to votekick again

```
import threading
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


def reset():
    global vote_started
    global users_voted
    vote_started = False
    users_voted.clear()
    print('[+] Timeout Finished')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def votekick(ctx, *, member: discord.Member, Reason=None):
    global vote_started
    global users_needed
    global kicked_user
    global member_to_be_kicked
    global channel
    global role
    t = threading.Timer(120.0, reset)
    if member == client.user:
        await ctx.send('[-] ok retard')
        return
    else:
        if not vote_started:
            kicked_user = member
            member_to_be_kicked = member
            vote_started = True
            users_voted.append(ctx.author.id)
            await ctx.channel.send(
                f'[+] A votekick has started to kick {member.display_name}. [{len(users_voted)}/{users_needed}]')
            t.start() # <========== This line
            print('[+] Timeout Started')
        else:
            if ctx.author.id in users_voted:
                await ctx.send('[-] Error: You have already voted.')
            else:
                if member != member_to_be_kicked:
                    await ctx.send(f'[-] A vote to kick {member_to_be_kicked.display_name} has already started. nice '
                                   f'try retard.')
                    return
                users_voted.append(ctx.author.id)
                if len(users_voted) < users_needed:
                    await ctx.channel.send(f'[+] Users voted: [{len(users_voted)}/{users_needed}]')
                else:
                    pass
        if len(users_voted) >= users_needed:
            invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(reason=None, max_uses=1)
            try:
                dm_channel = await member.create_dm()
                await dm_channel.send(invite)
            except:
                pass
            await ctx.channel.send(
                f"[+] [{len(users_voted)}/{users_needed}] users have voted to kick {member.display_name}.")
            await member.kick(reason=Reason)
            vote_started = False
            users_voted.clear()
            role = member.roles
            channel = ctx.channel
```

Comment: Of course the answer is so simple! Thanks!